# VBA to fill rows based on cell value in separate column

Tags: excel, vba

Hi the code works except the last line. I would like to fill rows G2:W2 based on a cell value in columns E & F. I'm fairly new to VBA is their a simple way to do this?

```
Sub TradeDump()


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsp As Worksheet
Dim wsc As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rnge As Range
Dim Rnger As Range

   Set wsp = Sheets("Pivot")
   Set ws = Sheets("Cashflow Fix Data")
   Set wsc = Sheets("Control")

   Period = wsc.Range("Term")

   ws.Range("E:F").ClearContents

   Set rng = wsp.Range(wsp.Range("G6"), wsp.Range("G6").End(xlDown))

   rng.Copy

For i = 1 To Period
   NextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   'get the Next Empty Row
   ws.Range("E" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

   'paste
Next i
 Set rnge = wsp.Range(wsp.Range("J6"), wsp.Range("J6").End(xlDown))

 rnge.Copy
For i = 1 To Period
   NextRowF = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   'get the Next Empty Row
   ws.Range("F" & NextRowF).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    'paste
Next i

 Set Rnger = ws.Range("G2:W2")

 Rnger.AutoFill Destination:=wsc.Range("Period")
End Sub
```

Comment: Turn on [Option Explicit](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) to help with your variable declarations.

Comment: What's not working on the last line? Are you receiving an error? Is the data filled to the range not what you expect?

Comment: Hi @PeterT thats correct nothing is filling. Is their a way to have G2:W2 fill down to the last populated cell in column F?

Comment: Your issue is that the destination range MUST include the actual source data. This means that `Rnger` and `wsc.Range("Period")` must overlap. This is how `Autofill` works. Yours isn't working because the source and destination are on different worksheets.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT when I change the destination to an exact destination range it works. However my concern is that you will only know the destination once column E and F are fully populate (in this cast the last cell in columns E and F is in row 37)
  `Set Rnger = ws.Range("G3:W3")`
  
  `Rnger.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G3:W37")`

Comment: Instead of using `AutoFill`, since you've already coded a solution in VBA you can perform the copy yourself. That way your destination range would not have to include the source range at all.

Comment: @PeterT Is there a way to just have that range fill down?

Comment: @PeterT I was able to figure it out thanks.                                                                      `Set Rnger = ws.Range("G3:W3")`
  
 `Rnger.AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("G3:W" & Range("F3").End(xlDown).Row)`

Comment: That's fine... but be aware that you **MUST** qualify your `Range` when you're getting the last row. The way you have it, your `Range` is coming from the currently active sheet. So use `Destination:=ws.Range("G3:W" & ws.Range("F3").End(xlDown).Row)` instead.